# Redirect works but rewrite doesn't on an Azure web app

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to redirect from my old ISP to my azure web site. I have set up the necessary DNS records. As I am using sub-folders on my Web App I need to set up redirection rules in the root web.config file to point from the domain name to the correct sub-folder of the main site.

It works perfectly when I have a redirect rule.

```
            <rule name="Works" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mysite.com$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/mysub"/>
            </rule>
```

However when I change to a Rewrite it fails. I really want a rewrite as I don't want the user to see the change of url in the browser.

```
            <rule name="Fails" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mysite.com$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/mysub"/>
            </rule>
```

I get the following message:

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite action should be a relative path, see the documentation:

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Rewrite_action

`A substitution string must always specify the URL path`

Comment: Thanks problem is if I make it relative it is relative to my old web site, i.e. <action type="Rewrite" url="/mysub"/> ends up as mysite.com/mysub which doesn't exist

Comment: if you want to move your site to Azure and apply a rewrite rule i would suggest forwarding your DNS directly to yoursite.azurewebsites.net (configure in the portal) and applying the rewrite rule in your new website on Azure.

Comment: What if you DO want to send to a different server? ie: A different web app / micro-service handling requests to a particular path? This is a perfectly valid scenario (ie: setting up a reverse proxy)